# Event Key from KeyboardEvent in android is unidentified

Tags: javascript, android, keyboard-events

In all browsers `event.key` is working fine but in the android `event.key` the result is `unidentified`.
For Web and IOS, it is working fine as expected but when it comes to Andriod it is giving `unidentified`

#### ANDROID

```
event.key: unidentified
event.code: ''
event.which: `229`
event.keyCode: `229`
```

#### WEB

```
event.key: 2
event.code: 'Digit2'
event.which: `50`
event.keyCode: `50`
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key